# Maven spring namespace not found

Tags: xml, spring, maven, xml-namespaces

I've trawled through a number of similar questions, but no one seems to have an answer for this problem, so I'm hoping someone will have a new solution to this issue:

I'm wrestling with this error:

```
2014-11-06 12:21:57 DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver:147 - Loaded schema mappings: {}
2014-11-06 12:21:58 DEBUG DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader:108 - Loading bean definitions
2014-11-06 12:21:58 DEBUG DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver:157 - Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {}

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [clientSpringConfig.xml]
```

Here is a chunk of my program's client-side POM.

```
 <execution>
        <id>myClient</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputFile>C:\Dev\MyAppDeploy\Client\MyAppClient.jar</outputFile>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>uk.co.mycom.myClient.ClientStart</Main-Class>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <includes>
                        <include>uk/co/mycom/myClient/**</include>
                        <include>uk/co/mycom/shared/**</include>
                        <include>com/esotericsoftware/**</include>
                        <include>org/springframework/**</include>
                        <include>org/apache/log4j/**</include>
                        <include>log4j.properties</include>
                        <include>org/apache/commons/logging/**</include>
                        <include>org/objenesis/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>uk/co/mycom/myAppServer/**</exclude>
                        <!--<exclude>resources/**</exclude>-->
                        <exclude>bat/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

I like Maven shade and feel loathe to move, but I need to use Spring client side, and so what worked before now no longer works. I've seem folk advise Maven Assembly plugin. But as far as I can work out, the result is the same: if two files match, one will overwrite the other.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: You are merging things together and next you are filtering things. Looks to me as if the `META-INF` isn't included...

Comment: Yes, M. Deinum. I think that might be it: I added  <include>META-INF/**</include> - which seems to have moved me onto new errors. Probably not a good post in that case: I'll remove it shortly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, to confirm: that was it!